# Jquery slide out side panel, but then resize rest of page to fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking at creating a page that start with a main area and a side column, such as this:

```
------------------------------
|           |                |
| side area |    main area   |
| 20% width |    80% width   |
|           |                |
------------------------------
```

And with the side column being able to be hidden or shown, to show the page with or without the column.

BUT...

When the side column is moved, I need the rest of the page to then resize to fill.

```
------------------------------
|                            |
|        main area           |
|        100% width          |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

And the side column can be toggled to show/hide, and the main area always resizes to fit.

Now, I know there are many examples of this online, but none seem to do fit the bill and get this working correctly as I need it.

There seem to be two main areas of all examples:

1) They use JQueryUI which I dont want to do. I already have JQuery loaded on the page, and would prefer to stick to JQuery without loading in other plugins if possible

2) They slide in/out the side column without affecting the rest of the page - the slide out div always seems to slide in/out over the top of the rest of the page, or push the rest of the page out of the way

Most other examples I see use an absolute positioned side column that just slides in or out over the rest of a fixed page.

I am thinking that maybe the best way to do this is to have two animations running on the button click - one to animate the side column width from 20% to 0%, and one to animate the main column width from 80% to 100%, but this seems a little messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work best by using CSS table-cells.

Doing the page in this way, I managed to make a two column page layout, and then animate the width of the left column down to 0, which allows the width of the right hand column to expand automatically to full width.

This works quite well in practice and cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/j3ptnff2/

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
    $('.side').animate({
        'width': '0'
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('.main').animate({
            'width': '100%'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: At a basic level, yes, that is what I suggested at the end of my question as being the only way I could see to do this. But in your example it hides the side column first, and then expands the main column. It would be better if the main column expanded as the side column reduced, in a more responsive way, rather than one then the other.